# How to add a text to every command typed in command line bash?

Tags: bash

I want to concatenate /dev/null 2>&1 to every command typed in a bash prompt so that all the output gets logged.I don't want to type it after every command, so it would be nice if it automatically gets concatenated/executed after I type a command, so that the output is suppressed.

How do I do it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Modify what in that file to get the desired result?

Answer (score 4):

Can't you use `script` instead? It logs all the input and output.

Comment: Can you give me an example on how to use script?

Comment: In the terminal, type `script` and hit enter. That's it.

Comment: Careful, you could end-up with a very large `typescript` file.